# Java runtime.exe() Error launching browser : error accessing current directory

Tags: java, browser, runtime, exec

I have been trying to launch browser from a java app on Linux. When this app is run for the first time browser don't get opened. The error log shows : shell-init: cannot get current directory getcwd : no such file or directory.

After this if u restart everything falls into place and browser opens fine.

I have tried many things like changing current directory to /tmp using SYstem.setPropert() , but nothing works.

There are many question on this site like this but they didn't help. Will appreciate if someone can provide a workaround.

Comment: Care to post some code?

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd ); This is what  i am trying to do.Cmd is basically concatenation of browser command plus the file to open

Comment: I tried doing System.setProperty("user.dir",/tmp);
But didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Without getting any details your Java code most probably have insufficient rights accessing the directory.

Comment: No i don't think permissions is an issue.Probably it is trying to access the directory which i have cleaned up and gives the error " cannot access current directory getcwd". That's why i try changing the current directory before calling the exec.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I found for this problem, since it does not matter where the browser is installed or whatever, java communicates with the operating system and makes a request to run the browser that is default.

```
String url = "https://yourdomain.org/";
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse( java.net.URI.create(url));
```